Re-insert data with updated values while retaining some columns
I'm working with a SQL Server database where I need to update and reinsert user data with some modified values while retaining other existing values. Here's a simplified version of the data structure and requirements:
Existing data:

Idx: unique identifier for users.
NetCode: code that needs to be updated.
EncryptCode: to be retained
FirstName: to be retained.
AccessLevelIdx: indicates user level
Email: to be retained
ParentIdx: UserIdx of the parent user, which should also be updated

Example data:
User AccessLevel2



Old Idx
OldNetCode
EncryptCode
FirstName
AccessLevelIdx
Email
ParentIdx




44
AAAA12_Alice
60A6A0BC07
Alice
2
alice@example.com
15



User AccessLevel3



Old Idx
OldNetCode
EncryptCode
FirstName
AccessLevelIdx
Email
ParentIdx




156
AAAA12_Sarah
F31CABEA06
Sarah
3
sarah@example.com
44


176
AAAA12_David
67694FF1EA
David
3
david@example.com
44



User AccessLevel4



Old Idx
OldNetCode
EncryptCode
FirstName
AccessLevelIdx
Email
ParentIdx




1081
AAAA12_Emily
D0789701C0
Emily
4
emily@example.com
156


1990
AAAA12_John
61368D2FB5
John
4
john@example.com
176



Updated values:

Idx: updated identifier.
NetCode: updated network code.
ParentIdx: should refer to the updated UserIdx

New duplicated user AccessLevel2



UserIdx
NetCode
EncryptCode
FirstName
AccessLevelIdx
Email
ParentIdx




2990
FFFF33_Alice
60A6A0BC07
Alice
2
alice@example.com
15



New duplicated user AccessLevel3



UserIdx
NetCode
EncryptCode
FirstName
AccessLevelIdx
Email
ParentIdx




3101
FFFF33_Sarah
F31CABEA06
Sarah
3
sarah@example.com
2990


3102
FFFF33_David
67694FF1EA
David
3
david@example.com
2990



New duplicated user AccessLevel4



UserIdx
NetCode
EncryptCode
FirstName
AccessLevelIdx
Email
ParentIdx




4101
FFFF33_Emily
D0789701C0
Emily
4
emily@example.com
3101


5012
FFFF33_John
61368D2FB5
John
4
john@example.com
3102



Attempt at a SQL script: here's what I have so far (Idx is the unique identifier)
INSERT INTO Users (NetCode, EncryptCode, FirstName, AccessLevelIdx, Email, ParentIdx)
    SELECT 
        'FFFF33_' + SUBSTRING(NetCode, CHARINDEX('_', NetCode) + 1, LEN(NetCode) - CHARINDEX('_', NetCode)),
        EncryptCode,
        FirstName,
        AccessLevelIdx,
        Email,
        ParentIdx
    FROM 
        Users
    WHERE 
        NetCode LIKE '%AAAA12_%' AND AccessLevelIdx = 2


INSERT INTO Users (NetCode, EncryptCode, FirstName, AccessLevelIdx, Email, ParentIdx)
    SELECT 
        'FFFF33_' + SUBSTRING(p.NetCode, CHARINDEX('_', p.NetCode) + 1, LEN(p.NetCode) - CHARINDEX('_', p.NetCode)),
        p.EncryptCode,
        p.FirstName,
        p.AccessLevelIdx,
        p.Email,
        p.ParentIdx
    FROM 
        Users p
    JOIN 
        Users d on p.ParentIdx = d.Idx
    WHERE 
        NetCode LIKE '%AAAA12_%' 
        AND p.AccessLevelIdx = 3 
        AND d.AccessLevelIdx = 2

Can someone assist me in writing the query to achieve the desired output?

What help do you need? What is not working? Is it something to do with determining ParentIdx ?

Why are you reinserting the data? It's not clear to me why you don't just run an UPDATE query and set the new NetCode directly.

@alex: I just want a clear understanding on how to create a query achieving the table presented above

@TangentiallyPerpendicular: I need to retain the old one because of historical data.

What about your script doesn't work?

@DaleK: The first script works and inserts the new user with AccessLevelIdx 2, but the second script does not insert the users under AccessLevelIdx 2 with the new ParentIdx based on the newly inserted using the first script.

So that is the most important thing to say in your question, you should open with that, because without saying that we have no idea what you are stuck on.

And with a little bit of searching you would find out that this question gets asked every other day, and the solution is generally based on using the output clause

Try this Fiddle query
Understanding the need as

need to update and reinsert user data with some modified values while
retaining other existing records.

Instead of

need to update and reinsert user data with some modified values while
retaining other existing values.

Full Query goes like this:
Create Table #Users (Idx INT IDENTITY(1,1) , NetCode varchar(20), EncryptCode varchar(20), FirstName varchar(15), AccessLevelIdx Int, Email varchar(25), ParentIdx Int )

Insert Into #Users  
Select   'AAAA12_Alice' NetCode, '60A6A0BC07' EncryptCode, 'Alice' FirstName, 2 AccessLevelIdx, 'alice@example.com' Email, 15 ParentIdx Union
Select  'AAAA12_Sarah' NetCode, 'F31CABEA06' EncryptCode, 'Sarah' FirstName, 3 AccessLevelIdx, 'sarah@example.com' Email, 44 ParentIdx Union
Select  'AAAA12_David' NetCode, '67694FF1EA' EncryptCode, 'David' FirstName, 3 AccessLevelIdx, 'david@example.com' Email, 44 ParentIdx Union
Select  'AAAA12_Emily' NetCode, 'D0789701C0' EncryptCode, 'Emily' FirstName, 4 AccessLevelIdx, 'emily@example.com' Email, 156 ParentIdx Union
Select  'AAAA12_John' NetCode, '61368D2FB5' EncryptCode, 'John' FirstName, 4 AccessLevelIdx, 'john@example.com' Email, 176 ParentIdx  

Select * from #Users
 
INSERT INTO #Users 
SELECT 'FFFF33_' + SUBSTRING(NetCode, CHARINDEX('_', NetCode) + 1, LEN(NetCode) - CHARINDEX('_', NetCode))  NetCode,
        EncryptCode,
        FirstName,
        AccessLevelIdx,
        Email,
        ParentIdx
    FROM 
        #Users
    WHERE 
        NetCode LIKE '%AAAA12_%' AND AccessLevelIdx = 2


;With  acl3 as 
(
Select 'FFFF33_' + SUBSTRING(NetCode, CHARINDEX('_', NetCode) + 1, LEN(NetCode) - CHARINDEX('_', NetCode))  NetCode,
        EncryptCode,
        FirstName,
        p.AccessLevelIdx,
        Email,
        d.Idx ParentIdx
FROM  #Users  p
    INNER JOIN (Select Idx, AccessLevelIdx from #Users Where NetCode LIKE '%FFFF33_%' ) d on (p.AccessLevelIdx - d.AccessLevelIdx) = 1
    WHERE 
         p.NetCode LIKE '%AAAA12_%' 
        AND p.AccessLevelIdx = 3
)
 
INSERT INTO #Users
Select * from acl3 Where ParentIdx is NOT NULL

;With acl4 as 
(
Select 'FFFF33_' + SUBSTRING(NetCode, CHARINDEX('_', NetCode) + 1, LEN(NetCode) - CHARINDEX('_', NetCode))  NetCode,
        EncryptCode,
        FirstName,
        p.AccessLevelIdx,
        Email,
        d.Idx ParentIdx
FROM  #Users  p
    INNER JOIN (Select Idx, AccessLevelIdx from #Users Where NetCode LIKE '%FFFF33_%' ) d on (p.AccessLevelIdx - d.AccessLevelIdx) = 1
    WHERE 
         p.NetCode LIKE '%AAAA12_%' 
        AND p.AccessLevelIdx = 4
)
 
INSERT INTO #Users
Select * from acl4 

Select * from #Users

Drop Table #Users


Does that produce the desired results?

Yes with the logic that I see in the desired output shown in the question.

"Understanding the need as "need to update and reinsert user data with some modified values while retaining other existing records." Instead of "need to update and reinsert user data with some modified values while retaining other existing values."" What? How does changing "values" to "records" change any meaning? In the literal context for SQL Server it makes less sense as tables don't have "records"; they have columns, rows and values.

I meant the historical data which needs to be retained as per devmonster's ask as records.
